# Using optional query parameters in F# Web Api project

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, f#, c#-to-f#

I was converting a C# webapi project to F# using the F# ASP.NET templates. Everything is working great except optional query parameters. I keep getting this error

```
{
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "messageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'start' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage] GetVendorFiles(Int32, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' in 'Thor.WebApi.VendorFilesController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'System.Reflection.Missing', but the parameter requires a value of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'."
}
```

F# function signature:

```
[<HttpGet; Route("")>]
member x.GetVendorFiles( [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue(100)>] count, [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue(null)>] start : Nullable<DateTime> ) =
```

C# function signature:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetVendorFiles(int count = 100,DateTime? start = null)
```

Does anyone know of any workarounds?

**Updated:**
I figured out the cause of this issue. ASP.NET extracts default values for controller actions [using ParameterInfo](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/0ee98f84b41b6bef6bde6945e2797de9dac7d48a/src/System.Web.Http/Controllers/ReflectedHttpParameterDescriptor.cs#L37). Apparently the F# compiler doesn't compile default values the same way as C# does (even with the `DefaultParameterValueAttribute`)

What's the best way or working around this? Would it be some filter that I need to inject or implement my own `ParameterBinding`?

Comment: could you specify default parameters in a specific route for the controller method?            `routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "MyController/GetVendorFiles/{count}/{start}",  defaults: new { count= 100, start = (DateTime?)null });`

Comment: @DLeh Not really because the existing front end application is using count and start as query parameters (not route parameters) so I'd like to have it be compatible with the existing code. Worst case I can change it to that

Comment: Just noticed that @Pavel has raised this as an [Mvc issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1923).  The issue contains further discussion and a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty much limited to workarounds, it seems.

What about using:

```
[<HttpGet; Route("")>]
member x.GetVendorFiles(count: Nullable<int>, start : Nullable<DateTime>) =
    let count = count.GetValueOrDefault(100)
    // or: let count = if count.HasValue then count.Value else 100
```

Comment: That's valid and I tried that, but the problem is that if you don't specify a start query parameter, I get the error above, i.e. it finds the route but because the reflection causes that error it fails before even getting to my handler code.

Answer (score 3):

You can work around this with a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` implementation.  The following code supports the use of `DefaultParameterValue` values when an action argument is missing and when an action argument has a value of type `System.Reflection.Missing`.

*The code is also in the Gist [ActionFilter for ASP.NET Web API DefaultParameterValue support in F#](https://gist.github.com/bentayloruk/92dd56bdc0adcb6dec45).*

```
namespace System.Web.Http

open System.Reflection
open System.Web.Http.Filters
open System.Web.Http.Controllers
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

/// Responsible for populating missing action arguments from DefaultParameterValueAttribute values.
/// Created to handle this issue https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1923
/// Note: This is for later version of System.Web.Http but could be back-ported.
type DefaultParameterValueFixupFilter() =
  inherit ActionFilterAttribute()
  /// Get list of (paramInfo, defValue) tuples for params where DefaultParameterValueAttribute is present.
  let getDefParamVals (parameters:ParameterInfo array) =
    [ for param in parameters do
        let defParamValAttrs = param.GetCustomAttributes<DefaultParameterValueAttribute>() |> List.ofSeq 
        match defParamValAttrs with
        // Review: we are ignoring null defaults.  Is this correct?
        | [x] -> if x.Value = null then () else yield param, x.Value
        | [] -> () 
        | _ -> failwith "Multiple DefaultParameterValueAttribute on param '%s'!" param.Name
    ]
  /// Add action arg default values where specified in DefaultParameterValueAttribute attrs.
  let addActionArgDefsFromDefParamValAttrs (context:HttpActionContext) =  
    match context.ActionDescriptor with
    | :? ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor as ad ->
      let defParamVals = getDefParamVals (ad.MethodInfo.GetParameters())
      for (param, value) in defParamVals do
        match context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue(param.Name) with
        | true, :? System.Reflection.Missing
        | false, _ ->
          // Remove is null-op if key not found, so we handle both match cases OK.
          let _ = context.ActionArguments.Remove(param.Name)
          context.ActionArguments.Add(param.Name, value)
        | _, _ -> ()
    | _ -> ()
  /// Override adding suport for DefaultParameterValueAttribute values.
  override x.OnActionExecuting(context) =
    addActionArgDefsFromDefParamValAttrs context
    base.OnActionExecuting(context)
  /// Override adding suport for DefaultParameterValueAttribute values.
  override x.OnActionExecutingAsync(context, cancellationToken) =
    addActionArgDefsFromDefParamValAttrs context
    base.OnActionExecutingAsync(context, cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use HttpRequestMessage and parse the query string dictionary.

EDITED...

To use HttpRequestMessage, let's say you have a query string page:

```
[<Route("api/Applications")>]
[<HttpGet()>]
member x.Get (message:HttpRequestMessage) = 
    let page = GetQueryStringParameter(message, "page")
```

I would probably use a helper method to parse the query string out of the HttpRequestMessage, something like this:

```
let GetQueryStringParameter (message:HttpRequestMessage, value) = 
    let value = List.ofSeq ( message.GetQueryNameValuePairs() )
                |> List.tryFind (fun item -> item.Key = value)
    match value with
    | Some x -> x.Value
    | None   -> ""
```

Comment: Could you make an example?